# Altium Designer 16.1 Can't find Pin in Place Menu

Tags: pcb, altium, pins, cad

I am new to Altium, so this is probably a stupid question. I want to place a pin in a schematic, as described [here](https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Pin((Pin))_AD).

But I cannot find pin in any of the menus.

[image]

[image]

No pins anywhere... What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you place Pins on the Sch Library editor, not on the Sch editor?

Answer (score 3):

After commenting I checked on Altium.

From the URL you provided:

[image]

Schematic Editor (edits SchDoc files to draw schematics) and the Schematic Library Editor (edits SchLib files to draw parts) are different things.

Here is the menu from the SchLib Editor:

[image]

And the menu that you posted from the SchDoc Editor:

[image]

Comment: Ok I did not realize those were two different things. Thanks so much!